# What is the fastest (performance) way to compare if a string is present in a large list of objects?

Tags: c#, string, list

Currently I have object which contains two strings:

```
class myClass
{
    public string string1 { get; set; }
    public string string2 { get; set; }

    public bool MatcheString1(string newString)
    {
        if (this.string1 == newString)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I then have a second class that makes a list of the aforementioned object using List.

```
class URLs : IEnumerator, IEnumerable
{
    private List<myClass> myCustomList;
    private int position = -1;

    //  Constructor
    public URLs()
    {
        myCustomList = new List<myClass>();
    }
}
```

In that class I’m using a method to check if a string is present in the list

```
//  We can also check if the URL string is present in the collection
public bool ContainsString1(string newString)
{
    foreach (myClass entry in myCustomList)
    {
        if (entry. MatcheString1(newString))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Essentially, as the list of objects grows to the 100,000 mark, this process becomes very slow. What is fast way to checking if that string is present?  I’m happy to create a List outside of the class to validation, but that seems hacky to me?

Comment: Use a set instead of a list. Hash-based sets have `O(1)` lookup (which may degrade to `O(n)` with collisions), tree-based sets have `O(logn)` lookup.

Comment: Aside: instead of `if (this.string1 == newString) { return true; } return false;` just do `return this.string1 == newString`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the list of items is stable, you can compute a hash-set of the matches, for example:

```
// up-front work
var knownStrings = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(var item in myCustomList) knownStrings.Add(item.string1);
```

(note that this is not free, and will need to be re-computed as the list changes); then, *later*, you can just check:

```
return knownStrings.Contains(newString);
```

which is then very cheap (O(1) instead of O(N)).

Comment: Hash set takes more memory than sorted array, and almost no difference O(1) and O(logN).

Comment: for any non-trivial N, O(1) and O(logN) are noticeably different - especially when compounded by checking lots of values; and the questions asks "fastest"

Comment: in case of 10k elements Log(10k) = 4 :-)

Comment: @sh1ng Yeah, but suppose you use the logarithm with base 100,000,000, then the logarithme of 10,000 is only 0.5. You see?

Comment: Is it much faster for less than 500k items? What's the cut off point

Comment: @ChrisS *that*, is a question for profiling your exact scenario ;p

Comment: Yes you right we have trade-off between memory use and cpu overhead. I guess searching over 100M is not the case of this question.

Comment: @sh1ng the question is about 100k; since the OP is asking about "fastest", this is certainly starting to get into "we should care about this to profile it multiple ways" territory

Comment: Memory usage is not really a concern for me at this stage as the program only being used to compile data scraped from webpages.
The list is actually URLS scraped from a website and there link names, i.e. <a href="https://google.com" >Google</a>

String1 is actually storing the URL , and the purpose is to check if the URL has been scrapped already.
So the question is, would building the hash-table in tandem each time a URL is added the best way to check if I’ve already scraped that URL?

Comment: @Geegory you can .Add to the hash-set, yes

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a different data structure, instead of a list, you could a dictionary where your objects are indexed by their `string1` property.

```
public URLs()
{
    myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, myClass>();
}
```

Since `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can *usually* [find elements in O(1) time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), you can perform that check very fast.

```
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(newString))
  //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Search over sorted array(list) takes O(logN)

```
        var sortedList = new SortedSet<string>();
        sortedList.Add("abc");
        // and so on
        sortedList.Contains("test");
```

Search over HashSet takes O(1), but I guess in case of 100k elements(Log(100000)=5), and almost no difference to the HashSet that takes more memory.

Comment: The sortedness of the `List<>` is only utilized if he uses `BinaraySort` method. However, this might not be what he wants. Edit: ***If*** he really wants to search a sorted collection, he could also consider using a `SortedSet<string>`.

Comment: Computers work on base 2 so log2(100,000) = 16. This makes a huge difference. And by the way: You should have mentioned that the element type should implement `IComparable`. Otherwise this will crash.

Comment: You are right in stating that a HashSet uses more memory but if it is created with a prebuild list using `new HashSet<SomeValue>(listOfValues)` the memory consumption is only slightly higher. Unfortunately HashSet doesn't allow setting its capacity directly because it is designed so that its capacity is always a prime number (and people wouldn't accept to set a capacity of 100000 and then actually getting a capacity of 108631).